# How do I fix a typo in mount command output "relatime"?

Tags: mount

I ran the mount command to see what was set up so far.
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64)
Output snippet:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8029452k,nr_inodes=2007363,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to fix? What is the goal?

Comment: That's not a typo. Relatime does not mean real time, it means relative time --> "rela"+"time". Does that answer your question?

Comment: Okay - "egg on face"  Thanks!

Comment: For truth's sake, thanks to muru's [thorough answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448369/1157519): "rel"+"a"+"time".

Answer (score 3):

The output is correct - it should be `relatime`. The output isn't meant to be standard English, and the word isn't supposed to be `relative` (or some other word).

There is an option named `atime` for `a`ccess `time`, and a variant of that option which is *relative* to something else was named `relatime`. From [`man mount`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/mount.8):

```
atime
   Do not use the noatime feature, so the inode access time is controlled by kernel
   defaults. See also the descriptions of the relatime and strictatime mount options.

noatime
   Do not update inode access times on this filesystem (e.g. for faster access on the
   news spool to speed up news servers). This works for all inode types (directories
   too), so it implies nodiratime.

[...]
relatime
   Update inode access times relative to modify or change time. Access time is only
   updated if the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change
   time. (Similar to noatime, but it doesn’t break mutt(1) or other applications that
   need to know if a file has been read since the last time it was modified.)
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's been a while, I'll do more research before posting essentially stupid questions, LOL